# How to get the button's reference in the cell as a subview when we have indexpath for tableview cell on long press gesture in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am new to iOS. I'm adding a button in a cell as sub-view like:

```
UIButton *updateProfilebtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    updateProfilebtn.frame = CGRectMake(200.0f, 5.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f);
    [updateProfilebtn setTitle:@"U" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     updateProfilebtn.tag = @"update",indexPath.row;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:updateProfilebtn];
    [updateProfilebtn addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(updateProfile:)
                        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
updateProfilebtn.hidden = YES).
```

As you can see I have set visibility hidden, because on a long press I need to show the button.

But the problem is how do I do this?
How do I get the reference of this button in a cell **on longpress of the uitableview** cell.

Also I want to show particular button for particular cell row not for all rows..

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Indexpath in a method as follow

```
UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0"))
    {
        cell = (UITableViewCell*)[sender superview];
    }
    else
    {
        cell = (UITableViewCell*)[[sender superview] superview];
    }

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Here you get indexpath.

**Edited :**
Also you can get it by following code :

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
indexPath = [tableview indexPathForItemAtPoint:[tableview convertPoint:btn.center fromView:[btn superview]]];
```

You get your Indexpath here.

Comment: I don't need indexpath.. i already have it.. i want reference for button in uitableviewcell

Comment: Oky sry i missunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `indexPath.row` as the `UIButton` tag.

```
myButton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

When you want to reference that button you can do it like this:

```
(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag: indexPath.row]
```

so you can get the button only for the cell you want.

Answer (score 0):

This try:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapBlankAction:)];
    tgr.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying. but that is I have already implemented. problem is to get the button's reference on long press of table view cell, so that i could set its visibility visible.. please explain if it could happen from your code.

Comment: you should add tapGesture on uitableviewcell while loading in cellforrowatindexpath mehtod

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass UITableViewCell and create a property for updateProfilebtn. Then do something like:

```
self.updateProfilebtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
self.updateProfilebtn.frame = CGRectMake(200.0f, 5.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f);
[self.updateProfilebtn setTitle:@"U" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.contentView addSubview:_updateProfilebtn];
[self.updateProfilebtn addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(updateProfile:)
                        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.updateProfilebtn.hidden = YES
```

This way, the cell always holds a reference to the button.

Now you can add a gesture recogniser after you set up the button, and have that gesture recogniser call a method within your cell subclass. Your view controller then doesn't need to keep a reference to the buttons in each cell.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressGesture:)];
longPressGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
[self addGestureRecognizer:longPressGestureRecognizer];
```

Then, still in your UITableViewCell subclass

```
-(void) handleLongPressGesture:(id)sender {
    self.updateProfilebtn.hidden = NO;
}
```

If you need to call back to your view controller, look into using a delegate.

Comment: how can i get the reference of button, using your code. if you please explain. in terms of code? Thanks

Comment: Ok..But if i made it global using self, it will set visibility for every update buttons for every cell. I want to get the particular update button reference whose cell i long pressed.. and show the update button for that cell only. Hope You understand!

Comment: Hi Shruti, using this method you wouldn't be making it global. You can create a subclass of UITableViewCell, called MyTableViewCell, so each cell is an instance of MyTableViewCell. Each of these has a property called updateProfilebtn. Perhaps look into how subclassing UITableViewCells works, it will be very helpful to you in the future.

Comment: Hi , I tried your code, but it doesn't work well , as i long press the first cell but it showed the update button for last row.. ?? While it should show for first cell only

Comment: Sounds like you didn't create a UITableViewCell subclass - all of the code I posted must be used within a subclass, or it will only work for the last created cell. Have a look at this link for how to use UITableViewCell subclasses - [http://code-and-coffee.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/how-to-use-custom-uitableviewcell.html]

Comment: please can you tell me about subclassing?

Comment: Sorry I messed up the link! Try this: http://code-and-coffee.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/how-to-use-custom-uitableviewcell.html

Comment: hi. I follow your link.. but now it is giving "nil" for my updateProfilebtn.

Answer (score 0):

I ll list out the steps you can do

1. Get the location of longPress gesture recognizer. Inn the longPress selector method do,

   `CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:self.view];`
2. No get the `tableViewCell` from using this point. For that you could use `indexPathForRowAtPoint` to get `indexPath` and further get the cell using that indexPath.
3. Now you have the cell contains the button you are looking for,
   use `viewWithTag` to get the button.

   `UIButton *btn = [cell.contentView viewWithTag: indexPath.row]`

Note: These are just steps which leads to the solution. If you have any doubts, can ask :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `button Tag` in following method.

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    updateProfilebtn.tag = (indexPath.row + 1);
    }
```

put following code in `viewDidLoad` method

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0; //seconds
    lpgr.delegate = self;
    [self.myTableView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
```

get your `button object` in following method

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.myTableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
    if (indexPath == nil) {
        NSLog(@"long press on table view but not on a row");
    } else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"long press on table view at row %d", indexPath.row);

    } else {
        NSLog(@"gestureRecognizer.state = %d", gestureRecognizer.state);
    }

    UIButton * btnTemp = (UIButton *)[self.myTableView viewWithTag:(indexPath.row + 1)];
    NSLog(@"your button = %@",btnTemp);



}
```

Comment: hi.. please can you tell me two things what delegates use for and what is [self.tblHenges] in your code?

Comment: The following `delegate` you need to use for `tableview`

`<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>`

Comment: and what is [self.tblHenges] ? Thanks

Comment: but if we have more than one button in table view cell?

Comment: then give tag different suppose you have one more button then use `secondbutton.tag = (1001 + indexpath.row)`.